# I cannot figure out how to add these elements, sum/while loop difficulty?

Tags: python, variables, while-loop, sum, constants

Basically, I am trying to get a rough total here based on the given inputs. I don't know why I cannot get it to add, despite using sum. I tried putting the entire thing into a while loop and defining it as sumTotal and that did nothing. I ultimately want to have it display the total saying "This is your undiscounted total: (insert the total here).

Currently, it runs and the total pops out as AAyes. Which is hilarious, but not what I need it to do. Any suggestions?

```
holidayInn = 120
showBoat = 230
mollyPitcher = 180
rideshare = 20
A = 180
B = 230
C = 120

# Declare variables
rooms = 0
hotel = 0
rideshare = "yes"
MOLLYP = "A" 
SHOWB = "B"
HOLIDAY = "C"


# Greet the user
print("Hello, and welcome to our program!" + \
      " Follow the prompts below to begin" + \
      " planning your vacation.")

# Ask about the number of guests
party = int(input("With how many people will you be traveling?" + \
                  "(Larger groups may qualify for a discount!): "))

# Display discount
if 5 < party <= 8:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 10% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party >= 9:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 30% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party < 5:
    print("Sorry, your purchase does not qualify for a discount.")

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Ask about the number of rooms
rooms = int(input("How many rooms will you be booking? " + \
                  "(please limit to 10 per transaction): ") )

# Ask about the number of nights
nights = int(input("For how many nights will you be staying? "))

# Display Hotels
print("Here are our available hotels:")
print("A. Holiday Inn: $120/night")
print("B. Showboat: $230/night")
print("C. Molly Pitcher Inn: $180/night")

# Ask which hotel
select1 = input("At which hotel will you be staying? " + \
                 "(Enter the capital letter that corresponds.)")

# Check validity of first selection
if select1 != MOLLYP and select1 != SHOWB and select1 != HOLIDAY:
    print("Error: Enter your selection as a capital letter.")

# Ask about ridesharing
select2 = input("Will you be ultizing our ride-sharing services on your travels?" + \
                 " (If so, 'yes' or hit any key for no.) ")
while select2 == "yes":
    print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
    break
sum = ((select1 * rooms * nights) + (nights * rideshare))
print(format(sum))
```

Comment: What did you put inside loop? A `while` with a `break` not in a condition is same as just an `if`. That loop is gonna run only once.

Comment: `sum = ((select1 * rooms * nights) + (nights * rideshare))` You have `str` and `int` variables mixed together here, so this will not give you the values you are looking for.  Consider using your debugger to step through the code and verify that all of the types and values are as expected at each line of execution.

Comment: `select1` and `rideshare` are strings.  Multiplying a string by a number just repeats the string that many times, i.e. `"hello" * 2` gives `hellohello`.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Basic `print` statements to show variable values and types will highlight the problems.

Comment: so input to select1 can be either A B or C, which are all declared as constants above with numbers. That's part of what's confusing me. And then rideshare is also declared as a constant number. What do I do to fix them?

Comment: _And then rideshare is also declared as a constant number_ You declare `rideshare = 20`, but a few lines later you declare `rideshare = "yes"`, so it isn't a number anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> so input to select1 can be either A B or C, which are all declared as constants above with numbers. That's part of what's confusing me.

`select1` is a string with the value `"A"`, `"B"`, or `"C"`.  You also have variables named `A`, `B`, and `C`.  There is no connection between those two things.  `select1` does not magically take on the value of the corresponding letter variable.

If you want to to do that, use a dictionary:

```
hotels = {
    "A": 120,  # Holiday Inn
    "B": 230,  # Showboat
    "C": 180   # Molly Pitcher Inn
}

choice = input("Enter hotel letter: ")
if choice in hotels:
    hotel_cost = hotels["choice"]
else:
    print("I don't recognize that hotel")
```

Or, because there are only three choices, it might be just as easy to use if/else:

```
choice = input("Enter hotel letter: ")
if choice == "A":
    hotel_cost = 120
elif choice == "B":
    hotel_cost = 230
elif choice == "C":
    hotel_cost = 180
else:
    print("I don't recognize that hotel")
```

Answer (score 0):

in rideshare you declare string "yes"
in MOLLYP you declare string "A"

```
holidayInn = 120
showBoat = 230
mollyPitcher = 180
rideshare = 20
A = 180
B = 230
C = 120

# Declare variables
rooms = 0
hotel = 0
rideshare = "yes" # because of that you have yes in your result
MOLLYP = "A" # declare string A in variable MOLLYP (A in your result) 
SHOWB = "B"
HOLIDAY = "C"
```

probably you want to declare like:

```
rideshare = 20 # 20
MOLLYP = A  # 180
SHOWB = B  # 230
HOLIDAY = C #120
```

Answer (score 0):

`select1` and `rideshare` are strings, not numbers. `select1` contains the name of the hotel entered by the user, but instead, you want the rate of the corresponding hotel. You can use a dictionary to store the numerical rate for each hotel:

```
hotels = {"HOLIDAY": 180,
          "SHOWB": 230,
          "MOLLYP": 180}
```

And here's how you can get the rate from the user input:

```
while select1 not in hotels:
    # Ask which hotel
    select1 = input("At which hotel will you be staying? " + \
                     "(Enter the capital letter that corresponds.)")

rate = hotels[select1] # get rate of hotel from dictionary
```

For `rideshare`, you need to set it to 0 or 20 based on the user input:

```
# Ask about ridesharing
select2 = input("Will you be ultizing our ride-sharing services on your travels?" + \
                 " (If so, 'yes' or hit any key for no.) ")
if select2 == "yes":
    print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
    rideshare = rideshare_rate
else: rideshare = 0
```

Here's a working implementation:

```
rideshare_rate = 20

# Declare variables
rooms = 0
hotel = 0
select1 = ""

hotels = {"HOLIDAY": 180,
          "SHOWB": 230,
          "MOLLYP": 180}

# Greet the user
print("Hello, and welcome to our program!" + \
      " Follow the prompts below to begin" + \
      " planning your vacation.")

# Ask about the number of guests
party = int(input("With how many people will you be traveling?" + \
                  "(Larger groups may qualify for a discount!): "))

# Display discount
if 5 < party <= 8:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 10% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party >= 9:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 30% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party < 5:
    print("Sorry, your purchase does not qualify for a discount.")

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Ask about the number of rooms
rooms = int(input("How many rooms will you be booking? " + \
                  "(please limit to 10 per transaction): ") )

# Ask about the number of nights
nights = int(input("For how many nights will you be staying? "))

# Display Hotels
print("Here are our available hotels:")
print("A. Holiday Inn: $120/night")
print("B. Showboat: $230/night")
print("C. Molly Pitcher Inn: $180/night")

while select1 not in hotels:
    # Ask which hotel
    select1 = input("At which hotel will you be staying? " + \
                     "(Enter the capital letter that corresponds.)")

rate = hotels[select1] # get rate of hotel from dictionary

# Ask about ridesharing
select2 = input("Will you be ultizing our ride-sharing services on your travels?" + \
                 " (If so, 'yes' or hit any key for no.) ")
if select2 == "yes":
    print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
    rideshare = rideshare_rate
else: rideshare = 0

sum = (rooms * nights) + (nights * rideshare)
print(format(sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some comments on your code:

1) select1 is a string so you need to convert it based on the response (if select1='A' then 180... so on

2) rideshare is initialized 2x. First as integer then secondly as string

3) use an "if condition" when response on rideshare is yes

```
  rideshare=0
  if select2 == "yes":
      print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
      rideshare=20
```

4) Your hotel charges per night and per room. Very expensive. I
    rather use airbnb.

Below is the working code:

```
#holidayInn = 120
#showBoat = 230
#mollyPitcher = 180
rideshare = 0
A = 180
B = 230
C = 120

# Declare variables
rooms = 0
hotel = 0
#rideshare = "yes"
MOLLYP = "A" 
SHOWB = "B"
HOLIDAY = "C"


# Greet the user
print("Hello, and welcome to our program!" + \
      " Follow the prompts below to begin" + \
      " planning your vacation.")

# Ask about the number of guests
party = int(input("With how many people will you be traveling?" + \
                  "(Larger groups may qualify for a discount!): "))

# Display discount
if 5 < party <= 8:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 10% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party >= 9:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 30% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party < 5:
    print("Sorry, your purchase does not qualify for a discount.")

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Ask about the number of rooms
rooms = int(input("How many rooms will you be booking? " + \
                  "(please limit to 10 per transaction): ") )

# Ask about the number of nights
nights = int(input("For how many nights will you be staying? "))

# Display Hotels
print("Here are our available hotels:")
print("A. Holiday Inn: $120/night")
print("B. Showboat: $230/night")
print("C. Molly Pitcher Inn: $180/night")

# Ask which hotel
select1 = input("At which hotel will you be staying? " + \
                 "(Enter the capital letter that corresponds.)")

# Check validity of first selection
if select1 != MOLLYP and select1 != SHOWB and select1 != HOLIDAY:
    print("Error: Enter your selection as a capital letter.")
if select1 == 'A':
    select1 = A
elif select1 == 'B':
    select1 = B
elif select1 == 'C':
    select1 = C
# Ask about ridesharing
select2 = input("Will you be ultizing our ride-sharing services on your travels?" + \
                 " (If so, 'yes' or hit any key for no.) ")
if select2 == "yes":
    print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
    rideshare=20
sum1 = ((select1 * rooms * nights) + (nights * rideshare))
print(format(sum1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The major issue that you're running into is the input you are receiving from the user and how you're handling it.

In this line:

```
# Ask which hotel
select1 = input("At which hotel will you be staying? " + \
                 "(Enter the capital letter that corresponds.)")
```

You are asking for the user to input a capital letter. Then down below:

```
sum = ((select1 * rooms * nights) + (nights * rideshare))
```

You are taking the variable, `select1` which equals some letter, call it `A` and multiplying it by the integer values of `rooms` and `nights`. When a string is multiplied by an integer `c`, it returns that string `c` times. This is why you're receiving the `AA` at the beginning of your return.

This is also why you're receiving the `yes`after the `AA`. The variable `rideshare` is stored as 'yes'. You are then multiplying it by some integer stored in `nights`. If you go back and put 2 in for that value, you'll see that it returns `yesyes` at the end of your output.

I would recommend storing the variables you have declared at the top of script into a dictionary for sake of readability and usefulness. I would also check to make sure the inputs of the user are integers when need be. If you would like more clarification, or would like me to help you further rewrite the code, feel free to ask.

Hope this helps you get started!

Answer (score 0):

The variable select1 contains a string. When you multiply a string by an integer n you are repeating the string n number of times. Example ("A" * 4 = "AAAA").

You need to match the inputted string with the appropriate variable (A,B, or C). I recommend creating a dictionary with the hotel prices:

```
#Get rid of these:
#A = 180
#B = 230
#C = 120

#Use this instead:
hotel_prices = {
    'A': 180,
    'B': 230,
    'C': 120
}
```

After your validate the input, you can get the int price using the dictionary:

```
# Check validity of first selection
if select1 != MOLLYP and select1 != SHOWB and select1 != HOLIDAY:
    print("Error: Enter your selection as a capital letter.")

select1 = hotel_prices[select1]
```

You have the same problem with the variable rideshare. You first set it to an int (rideshare = 20) and then change it to a string (rideshare = 'yes'). Get rid of the second declaration, if you will not use it. You can check for the rideshare option using an if statement:

```
if select2 == "yes":
    print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
else:
    rideshare = 0
```

There's other improvements that can be made here, but hopefully this solves the problem that you were having. Here's the complete code:

```
#holidayInn = 120
#showBoat = 230
#mollyPitcher = 180
#rideshare = 20
#Get rid of these
#A = 180
#B = 230
#C = 120
hotel_prices = {
    'A': 180,
    'B': 230,
    'C': 120
}

# Declare variables
rooms = 0
hotel = 0
#rideshare = "yes"
MOLLYP = "A" 
SHOWB = "B"
HOLIDAY = "C"


# Greet the user
print("Hello, and welcome to our program!" + \
      " Follow the prompts below to begin" + \
      " planning your vacation.")

# Ask about the number of guests
party = int(input("With how many people will you be traveling?" + \
                  "(Larger groups may qualify for a discount!): "))

# Display discount
if 5 < party <= 8:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 10% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party >= 9:
    print("Cool! Your selection qualifies for a 30% discount" + \
          "that will be applied at the end.")
elif party < 5:
    print("Sorry, your purchase does not qualify for a discount.")

# -----------------------------------------------------------------

# Ask about the number of rooms
rooms = int(input("How many rooms will you be booking? " + \
                  "(please limit to 10 per transaction): ") )

# Ask about the number of nights
nights = int(input("For how many nights will you be staying? "))

# Display Hotels
print("Here are our available hotels:")
print("A. Holiday Inn: $120/night")
print("B. Showboat: $230/night")
print("C. Molly Pitcher Inn: $180/night")

# Ask which hotel
select1 = input("At which hotel will you be staying? " + \
                 "(Enter the capital letter that corresponds.)")

# Check validity of first selection
if select1 != MOLLYP and select1 != SHOWB and select1 != HOLIDAY:
    print("Error: Enter your selection as a capital letter.")

select1 = hotel_prices[select1]

# Ask about ridesharing
select2 = input("Will you be ultizing our ride-sharing services on your travels?" + \
                 " (If so, 'yes' or hit any key for no.) ")
# While statement is not necessary here:
#while select2 == "yes":
#    print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
#    break
#
# Use an if statement:
if select2 == "yes":
    print("This adds a $20 additional cost per day.")
else:
    rideshare = 0

sum = ((select1 * rooms * nights) + (nights * rideshare))
print(format(sum))
```